# Unable to run the sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to run this SQL Query from last evening, but i am not able to execute the command.
Here is the SQL Syntax:

```
SELECT * , ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( 'lat' )) * SIN( RADIANS( 37.387138 )) + 
COS( RADIANS( 'lat' )) * COS( RADIANS( 37.387138 )) * COS( RADIANS( 'lng' ) 
- RADIANS( -122.083237 )) ) * 6380 AS distance 
FROM 'restaurants' WHERE distance < 10 ORDER BY distance
```

I am getting this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MariaDB server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'FROM 'restaurants' WHERE distance < 10' at line 1
```

Any advise? thank you

Comment: `restaurants` is a table name and (if quoted at all) should be in backticks (`\``), not single quotes. The same applies to the column names `lat` and `lng`.

Comment: Note that once you fix that you will get an error from `distance`, as you can't use column aliases in `WHERE` clauses. See the second duplicate for how to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL, along with most other flavors of SQL, does not allow referring to an alias in the `WHERE` clause defined in a select at the same level of the query.  So, your `WHERE` clause is invalid.  Fortunately MySQL has overloaded its `HAVING` operator to allow referring to an alias, so you may try that:

```sql
SELECT * , ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( lat )) * SIN( RADIANS( 37.387138 )) + 
    COS( RADIANS( lat )) * COS( RADIANS( 37.387138 )) * COS( RADIANS( lng ) 
    - RADIANS( -122.083237 )) ) * 6380 AS distance 
FROM restaurants
HAVING distance < 10
ORDER BY distance;
```

Also note that your `restaurants` table, and `lat`/`lng` columns, should not be in single quotes.